# Xtragrid SelectionChanged or Alternative

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm having an issue here.

I have a `XtraGrid` in winforms with a multiselect mode true, I need to validate if the row I'm selecting, if it matches a condition, select it, if not, deselect it. I'm currently using the `SelectionChanged` method like this:

```
private void grdProducts_SelectionChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Data.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        int[] selectedRows = view.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
        {
            if (view.IsRowSelected(selectedRows[i]))
            {
                Product product = view.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as Candidato;
                ProcessStatus processStatus = _procesoStatusService.GetProduct(product.IdProduct);
                if (processStatus.Proccess.Inventory == (int)ProductInventory.Yes)
                {
                    view.UnselectRow(selectedRows[i]);
                    XtraMessageBox.Show("One or more products are currently in inventory.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The problem here is when the code reaches the `view.UnselectRow(selectedRows[i]);` line, the `SelectionChanged` method is called again and the program send multiple `XtraMessageBox`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [`BaseView.BeginSelection`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_BeginSelectiontopic) method before your code and [`BaseView.EndSelection`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_EndSelectiontopic) method after your code. This will prevent the `ColumnView.SelectionChanged` event to raise.
Here is example:

```
private void grdProducts_SelectionChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Data.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = sender as GridView;
    if (view == null) return;
    view.BeginSelection();
    try
    {
        int[] selectedRows = view.GetSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
        {
            if (view.IsRowSelected(selectedRows[i]))
            {
                Product product = view.GetRow(selectedRows[i]) as Candidato;
                ProcessStatus processStatus = _procesoStatusService.GetProduct(product.IdProduct);
                if (processStatus.Proccess.Inventory == (int)ProductInventory.Yes)
                {
                    view.UnselectRow(selectedRows[i]);
                    XtraMessageBox.Show("One or more products are currently in inventory.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        view.EndSelection();
        throw;
    }
    view.EndSelection();        
}
```